# GatsbyJS in Electron, how to solve issue with file://

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, gatsby

I'm trying to bundle a GatsbyJS application inside Electron starting from the gatsby default starter (boilerplate repository).

After created the main.js file for electron using this code:

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
```

I've an issue with urls, in fact it's not able to load js files since they uses an absolute paths:

In Electron console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/app-bab7028ef226fa82b9a6.js
```

Is there any way to fix it in Electron or GatsbyJS?

Comment: However i think it's a limitation of Gatsby, issue here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10086

Comment: Use gatsby serve and `BrowserWindow.loadURL` instead of `.loadFile`

Comment: Or use [electron-serve](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-serve)